# How to output fields to html template correctly from User model in Django ORM?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

Task: Create a Django SQL query, pulling out only the required fields. Submit them to the template.

I have a Post model with a foreign key to a standard User model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Post(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField("date published", auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="posts"
    )
```

Here is the required fragment in the HTML template, where you need to insert the author's name:

```
{% for post in posts %}
<h3>
    Author: {{ post.author.first_name }}, Date: {{ post.pub_date|date:'d M Y' }}
</h3>
```

view function:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Post


def index(request):
latest = (
    Post
    .objects
    .order_by('-pub_date')[:10]
    .select_related('author')
    .values('pub_date', 'author__first_name')
)
return render(request, 'index.html', {'posts': latest})
```

Here's what the page fragment looks like on the local server:
[template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQ6gA.png)
And here is the final sql query shown by django debug toolbar:
[Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cibDr.png)

In the user table, I have one user and all posts are related to him. If I do not use `.values` in the view, then all the attributes of the author that I request in the template are displayed perfectly (for example, last_name, username, get_full_name()), but then sql requests all the fields of the user table (as it usually does), and I want get only certain ones to save memory. I also tried to recreate the project, use User = get_user_model(). Nothing helped.

Comment: The QuerySet reference is really complete and clear, you'll find a lot of things in there which will help fine tune your queries. In that case, you want this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.only

Comment: @Clepsyd Yes, this is indeed what I was looking for. I am very glad that now everything works beautifully. You are very cool!

Answer (score -1):

You can refer this:

## Model

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class CoachDetailsModel(models.Model):

     coach_id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
     name=models.CharField(max_length=100,help_text="Enter FullName")
     email=models.EmailField(max_length=100,help_text="Enter Email id")
     contact=models.BigIntegerField(help_text="Enter Mobile Number" ,null=True)
     password=models.CharField(max_length=100,help_text="Enter Password")
     coach_status=models.CharField(max_length=100,default='pending',help_text="Enter Password")

     def __str__(self):
         return self.email

     class Meta:
         db_table="Coach_details"
```

## Views

```
def coach_register(request):
  if request.method == "POST":
        name= request.POST.get('name')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        contact = request.POST.get('contact')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        CoachDetailsModel.objects.create(name=name,email=email,contact=contact,password=password)
  return render(request,'coach/coach-register.html')

  ### url
path('coach-register',coachviews.coach_register,name='coach_register'),
```

## Html page

```
                                  <form method="POST" id="contactForm" name="contactForm" class="contactForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                    {% csrf_token %}
                                    <div class="row">
                                    
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="label" for="subject">Enter UserName</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="subject" placeholder="UserName">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="label" for="subject">Enter Contact</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="contact" id="subject" placeholder="Contact">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="label" for="subject">EMAIL-ADDRESS</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="subject" placeholder="Email">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <div class="form-group-col-6">
                                                <label class="label" for="subject">PASSWORD</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="password" id="subject" placeholder="Password">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    
                                    
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <div class="form-group col-9">
                                                <input type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-primary">
                                                <div class="submitting"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
```